# Ajax/JQuery/JSON Forms

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, jsonp

I've got a form which I need to post the information to an external site, but for some reason I'm getting an error:

> Error: [Exception... "Access to
>   restricted URI denied"  code: "1012"
>   nsresult: "0x805303f4
>   (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location:
>   "jquery.core.1-3-2.min.js Line: 19"]
>   Source File: jquery.core.1-3-2.min.js
>   Line: 19

Here's the code that I'm using to do the form (or attempt to do so):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function() {

  $(".FormButtons").click(function() {

    var name        = $("input#contactDataFirstName").val();
    var lname       = $("input#contactLastName").val();
    var gender      = $("input#contactDataGender").val();
    var dobd        = $("input#contactDataDateOfBirthday").val();
    var dobm        = $("input#contactDataDateOfBirthmonth").val();
    var doby        = $("input#contactDataDateOfBirthyear").val();
    var mobile      = $("input#contactDataMobilePhoneNumber").val();
    var street      = $("input#contactDataStreetAddress").val();
    var suburb      = $("input#contactDataSuburbTownCity").val();
    var postcode    = $("input#contactDataPostcode").val();
    var country     = $("input#contactDataCountry").val();
    var state       = $("input#contactDataCountrySubdivisionIDNew").val();
    var password    = $("input#contactDataPassword").val();
    var email       = $("input#contactDataEmail").val();
    var remail      = $("input#contactDataReceiveEmail").val();
    var rmail       = $("input#contactDataReceiveMail").val();
    var rsms        = $("input#contactDataReceiveSMS").val();

    var dataString = 'contactDataFirstName='+ name + '&contactLastName=' + lname + '&contactDataGender=' + gender + '&contactDataDateOfBirthday=' + dobd + '&contactDataDateOfBirthmonth=' + dobm + '&contactDataDateOfBirthyear=' + doby + '&contactDataMobilePhoneNumber=' + mobile + '&contactDataStreetAddress=' + street + '&contactDataSuburbTownCity=' + suburb + '&contactDataPostcode=' + postcode + '&contactDataCountry=' + country + '&contactDataCountrySubdivisionIDNew=' + state + '&contactDataPassword=' + password + '&contactDataEmail=' + email + '&contactDataReceiveEmail=' + remail + '&contactDataReceiveMail=' + rmail + '&contactDataReceiveSMS=' + rsms;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "path_to_url",
      //dataType: "jsonp", 
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('#contact_form').html("<div id=\"message\"></div>");
        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
        .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
        .hide()
        /*.fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
        });*/
      }
     });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Could someone please help me post my data to the external website :)

Comment: Maybe it doesn't matter, but you may want to remove that URL from your code example. A regular GET request to it shows your original entry form. I hope you didn't wire this to your storage layer already.

Comment: yeh that's the form i'm trying to implement on my server, might sound strange, but i need the form to send the info to that url (where the original form is) and also to send info onto my database.. hense all the problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to cross domain restrictions it is impossible to POST with AJAX to a different domain. The way `jsonp` works is it inserts a `<script>` tag inside the DOM so it performs a GET request.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers have a security concept called same-origin policy whereby AJAX requests can only access the domain from which the page source has originated from (with some minor caveats and workarounds, but long and short..)

Your best bet is to POST to a local page which acts as a proxy, it will do the "real" HTTP POST to the external site.

Comment: sorry to sound dumb, but how can i get the local page to forward the data on?

Answer (score 3):

You can check [this site](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use variable for every input in the form.

you can use $("form").serialize( ) to post all the input fields.

```
var str = $("form").serialize();
```

see here [jquery form Serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize)